# Shapeless: Why align does not work with singleton types?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I expected this code to compile

```scala
import shapeless._
import record._
import ops.record._
import ops.hlist.Align
import syntax.singleton._

case class From(i: Int, s: String, a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)
case class To(j: Int, s1: String, s2: String, a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)
val f = From(1, "FROM", 1, 1, 1)

val fromGen = LabelledGeneric[From]
val toGen = LabelledGeneric[To]

val lgenRepr = fromGen.to(f)
val modified = lgenRepr.renameField('i, 'j) - 's + ('s1 ->> "S1") + ('s2 ->> "S2")

val align = Align[modified.type, toGen.Repr]

toGen.from(align(modified))
```

but if fails with

```
could not find implicit value for parameter alm: shapeless.ops.hlist.Align[modified.type,toGen.Repr]
 val align = Align[modified.type, toGen.Repr]
```

There is [a trick](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/shapeless-2.3.2/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/labelledgeneric.scala#L83) with constructing the needed type using `labelled.FieldType`, but it doesn't explain how to remove fields, so if it's impossible to make `Align` work with singleton type, it would be useful to know how to deal with those fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `modified.type` is a little *too* precise ... it's the singleton type of that particular val, not the computed record type. To do this on the REPL the following works just fine,

```
@ modified.align[toGen.Repr] 
res14: toGen.Repr = 1 :: S1 :: S2 :: 1 :: 1 :: 1 :: HNil
```